# Throttling user by IP address using htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am looking for a way to throttle requests by IP address via htaccess, php and file system.

Perhapse following these steps:

1. in php: if too many requests are made in a short period of time creating root/ips/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.txt
2. in htaccess: `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/ips/%{REMOTE_ADDR}\.txt -f`
3. in htaccess: if file exists redirecting to /too_busy_right_now_sorry.php with header refresh 5 sec
4. in php: unlink(root/ips/xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx.txt)

What are the best practices to throttle requests by IP address in Apache?

Comment: You start by looking at what Apache has built in: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_ratelimit.html

Comment: Thanks! I am looking for a way to controle the limitation by ips